# Line width in raphaeljs

Tags: svg, raphael

Is it real to make line with 1px weight in SVG or raphaeljs?

The follow code

```
 var p = Paper.path("M1 1 L50 1");
 p.attr("stroke", "#D7D7D7");
 p.attr("stroke-width", "1");
 p.attr("opacity", 0.5);
```

draw line which looks like 2px or 3px. Any alternative?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7589650/drawing-grid-with-jquery-svg-produces-2px-lines-instead-of-1px

Comment: I came here when researching a similar issue: I had a raphael canvas that was being shifted left -0.5px in CSS.  The cause was renderfix() which was implemented for the above situation.  Find more here: https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/issues/614

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When SVG lines lie at their apparently correct coordinates they actually lie inbetween pixels, so when you state `M1 1 L50 1` it paints half a pixel on the top and the other half in the bottom of the pixel, making it look like a thick, semitransparent line.

To solve this problem you need to either paint at half pixels, or translate your elements half a pixel, ie. `element.translate(0.5, 0.5)`

You can see the blurry and sharp lines here:
http://jsfiddle.net/k8AKy/

Answer (score 6):

You should also use the `Paper.renderfix()` function since you do not know which browser your users will be using.

From the [documentation](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.renderfix)

> Fixes the issue of Firefox and IE9 regarding subpixel rendering. If
>   paper is dependant on other elements after reflow it could shift half
>   pixel which cause for lines to lost their crispness. This method fixes
>   the issue.

Answer (score 4):

This links take you point what's going wrong with integer coordinates and why **+0.5** was fixed edge blurring (with nice *pictures*!!):

- http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#pixel-madness
- http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/design/the-problem-with-svg-and-canvas/

Compare:

[image: blurred]

with **+0.5**:

[image]

You can avoid **+0.5** by:

```
SVG_Area.setAttribute("viewBox", "0.5 0.5 " + width + " " + height);
```

or by wrapper:

```
function fiXY(x) { return parseInt(x) + 0.5; }

var rect = document.createElementNS(SVGobj.svgNS, "rect");
rect.setAttribute("x", fiXY(x));
rect.setAttribute("y", fiXY(y));
```

or by:

```
SVG_Area.setAttribute("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
```

which effect on all shapes in you SVG image....

Comment: Also look to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051703/blurring-borders-in-svg-raphael-js/