# Width of the line path in Raphael is 2px instead of 1px

Tags: javascript, raphael

OK, so far I have this code:

```
var fillerLine = {
                            'color': 'white',
                            'cursor': 'pointer'
                        }

                        var line1 = paper1.path("M2 2");
                        line1.attr(fillerLine);
                        var anim = Raphael.animation({path: "M2 2L100 2"}, 500);
                        line1.animate(anim.delay(3000));
```

But the line1 is not sharp at all. It looks like 2px wide instead of 1px as normal line . How can I reset it to 1px and set color of the line to white?

How can I get 1px line?

EDIT: seems like this problem with Firefox [Line width in raphaeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036519/line-)**width-in-raphaeljs I will try if it can be fixed using renderfix();**

Comment: Do somebody know where should I put this code so it is working Paper.renderfix();
? I have tried on the begining and at the end, but without any results. It is still blurry and not crisp.

Comment: renderfix is not working if I use it like paper1.renderfix();

Comment: I have to use 2.5 instead of 3 and then it works, however it is weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to use 2.5 instead of 3 and then it kinda works.

Answer (score 2):

This question already discussed:

- [Line width in raphaeljs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8036519/line-width-in-raphaeljs/)
- [Blurring borders in SVG (Raphael.js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7051703/blurring-borders-in-svg-raphael-js/)

This links take you point what's going wrong with integer coordinates and why **+0.5** was fixed edge blurring (with nice *pictures*!!):

- http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#pixel-madness
- http://kilianvalkhof.com/2010/design/the-problem-with-svg-and-canvas/

You can avoid **+0.5** by:

```
SVG_Area.setAttribute("viewBox", "0.5 0.5 " + width + " " + height);
```

or by wrapper:

```
function fiXY(x) { return parseInt(x) + 0.5; }

var rect = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "rect");
rect.setAttribute("x", fiXY(x));
rect.setAttribute("y", fiXY(y));
```

or by:

```
SVG_Area.setAttribute("shape-rendering", "crispEdges");
```

which effect on all shapes in you SVG image....

Comment: Setting the 'shape-rendering' attribute on the individual SVG nodes fixed the problem for me without affecting other elements that could benefit from anti-aliasing.

Answer (score 0):

```
line1.attr({'stroke-width':'1'});
```

rather add it to fillerline for a reusable approach ....